# Can Selfhosted WebApi with PushStreamContent handle multiple requests?

Tags: streaming, asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

I'm using HttpSelfHostServer to host my WebApi. I return a PushStreamContent like this

```
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            var response = request.CreateResponse();
            response.Content = new PushStreamContent(OnStreamAvailable, "text/eventstream");
            return response;
        }
```

Everthing is working as expected until I made a second request to my api. The first request is blocking and the second one won't reach the Get-function until I close the first request.

I have setup my configuration like this

```
            HttpSelfHostConfiguration config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(_baseAddress);
            config.TransferMode = System.ServiceModel.TransferMode.Streamed;
            config.MaxConcurrentRequests = 10;
```

Why is the first call blocking the second one?

**Edit: 
Here is my complete controller:**

```
    public class PushController : ApiController
    {
        private static readonly ConcurrentBag<StreamWriter> _Writers = new ConcurrentBag<StreamWriter>();


        public HttpResponseMessage Get(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            var response = request.CreateResponse();
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
            response.Content = new PushStreamContent(OnStreamAvailable, "text/event-stream");
            return response;
        }

        private void OnStreamAvailable(Stream stream, HttpContent content, TransportContext context)
        {
            _Writers.Add(new StreamWriter(stream) { AutoFlush = true });
        }

        public static void Say(string text)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var w in _Writers)
                {
                    w.Write("data:{ text : \"" + text + "\" }\n\n");
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you do in *OnStreamAvailable* ?

Comment: I've added the ApiController.

Comment: Hi @ErikZ, did you find the cause at that time?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why self-hosted WebAPI can't serve concurrent requests i.e. dispatch the second request onto a separate thread.

But... I think you should always `Close` the stream `PushStreamContent` gives you once you've written all you are going to. You haven't added a `Content-Length` header, so the client has no idea when to stop waiting on more data. Closing the output stream will tell the client there is no more coming.